# What does the variance σ² of a random signal actually indicate?

Tags: power, ac

I was reading somewhere that variance σ² indicates total power of a random signal. And somewhere it was given as it indicates the AC Power of random signal. Can you please help me to understand this.

[Please check this](http://12000.org/my_courses/calpoly_pomona/ECE_405_communications/scanned_sheat_sheets/2010_07_27_18_37_35.pdf). Does this imply \$E[X^2] = \text{Total Power} = \text{DC} + \text{AC}\$ and \$E[x]^2\$ indicates only DC power.

So is \$\text{Variance} = 2\cdot\text{DC Power} + \text{AC power}\$ of random signal x(t)..???

Comment: The answer isnt going to change. You should take this up in the math forum with statisticians.  This is objectively a math question and you get a better explanation from mathy people, if you want full details and concepts.  The application to signals or electronics is immaterial to your question.

Comment: The sum of the squares of the magnitude (for discrete), or the integral of the squares of the magnitude (for continuous) is defined as energy.  Power is just the energy divided by the interval as a sort of average. Not the same as Joules or Watts, dont get confused.  This expression is mathematically equivalent to a variance.

Comment: [Please Check this](http://12000.org/my_courses/calpoly_pomona/ECE_405_communications/scanned_sheat_sheets/2010_07_27_18_37_35.pdf). Is this explanation correct ?

Comment: [Does this imply](http://12000.org/my_courses/calpoly_pomona/ECE_405_communications/scanned_sheat_sheets/2010_07_27_18_37_35.pdf)  E[X^2] = Total Power = DC + AC and (E[x])^2 indicates only DC power. So is Variance = 2*DC Power + AC power of random signal x(t)..???

Comment: your whole question doesn't make much sense. You already got an answer. and, also, your notation doesn't work out.

Comment: Yeah I noted that. Thank you for pointing me that. Also the expression of variance is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigma (standard deviation) uses the same formula as when calculating the RMS value of a voltage or current with no dc content. Inspect the two formula and see. Sigma squared is therefore a measure of power.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you mean, the variance gives the AC power of random signal x(t).

Comment: Yes, variance represents the power into a 1 ohm load when the average dc level is zero.